# How to copy an OleVariant array efficiently to my own structure?

Tags: arrays, delphi, com

I am trying to copy an `OleVariant` array to my own structure. I received the `OleVariant` from an external COM call.

The size is 1000 x 500 elements (I don't know if its the same as this Structure Definition: `array of array of OleVariant`).

Currently, I am trying to achieve something like:

`result := Copy(Source, Amount)`

But the `OleVariant` structure is in my way.

If I use a "classical" loop, it works, but it is slow (very slow).

`aResult` is currently defined as `TData = array of array of string;`

```pascal
procedure CopyResult(aResultCount: Integer; var aResult: TData; aSource: Variant);
var
  i, j: Integer;
  bVariantConversion: boolean;
begin    
  SetLength(aResult, aResultCount, VarArrayHighBound(aSource[0], 1));
  bVariantConversion := NullStrictConvert; // settings to manage how string conversion for Variant is handled.
  NullStrictConvert := False;
  try
    for i := VarArrayLowBound(aSource, 1) to VarArrayHighBound(aSource, 1) do
    begin
      for j := VarArrayLowBound(aSource[i], 1) to pred(VarArrayHighBound(aSource[i], 1)) do
      begin
        //nearly every execution pause is somewhere in this String Conversion or Array Function.
        aResult[i][j] := aSource[i][j]; //implicit conversion to string ... 
      end;
    end;
  finally
    NullStrictConvert := bVariantConversion;
  end;
end;
```

As @Remy Lebau mentioned the bounds Check for the Vararray[x][y] access is the routine my source burns its time. I am trying to eliminate this kind of acces by going directly to the OleVariantArray Elements.

Aftermath...
trying to Determine my Structure i think i found the Root.

```
  tmyVarType := VarType(aSource); //8204 => Array(VT_ARRAY = 0x2000 = 8192) + variant(VT_VARIANT = 0x000C = 12) 
  tmyVarType := VarType(aSource[0]); //8204
  tmyVarType := VarType(aSource[0][0]); //3 VT_I4 = 0x0003 = 3 is integer and this is correctly changin for the fields.
```

So i try to acess the Source without the build in functions to avoid the bounds check.

Comment: One way to speed up the code is to get rid of all the repeated `VarArray(Low|High)Bound()` calls in the loops. You know the array has a fixed size, so calculate the size and cache it into local variables before entering the loops. Looks like you already have the outer size from `aResultCount`, so all you really need is the inner size, which is `VarArrayHighBound(aSource[0], 1) - VarArrayLowBound(aSource[0], 1) + 1` (not `VarArrayHighBound(aSource[0], 1)`  by itself).

Comment: As for the actual copying of data, using `VarArrayLock()` is not very useful unless you know the data type that the `Variant` array holds in each element. Is it `VT_BSTR` (array of OLE strings), `VT_VARIANT` (array of OLE variants), etc? You likely can't get away from copying each element individually, but at least `VarArrayLock()` would allow you to use pointer arithmetic to access elements quicker instead of using the `[]` operator, which delegates to `VarArrayGet()`, and does bounds checks. What does `VarType()` return for the outer array `aSource`, and each inner array `aSource[i]`?

Comment: It would help if you could tell us what `VarType(aSource)` results. It determines what the data is you get access to by `VarArrayLock`.

Comment: @StijnSanders I think i understand the Structure now. I am Documenting my progress in the Question.   tmyVarType := VarType(aSource);
  tmyVarType := VarType(aSource[0]);
  tmyVarType := VarType(aSource[0][0]); the first 2 get me a 8204 which is a variant Array and the last one is 3 Integer. But its changing accordingly to every cell i call VarType for. I guess i can see a solution now.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes everytime i hit pause iam somewhere in the Loop for bound check. I try to avoid the "std" function and write mine. Question will be edited multiple times ...  as i progrss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest bottleneck in this code is the bounds checking performed by the `[]` operator on each `Variant` array, and potentially on your `aResult` array, too.  Since you are already handling the bounds in each loop, there is no need to verify the bounds inside of the loops as well.

So, if performance is an issue for you, then you can use `VarArrayLock()` to access the underlying `Variant` elements in each array, using pointer arithmetic to move between them, eliminating those redundant bounds checks.

You should also reduce the redundant calls to `VarArray(Low|High)Bound(aSource[i], 1)` on each iteration of the outer array, since you claim the inner arrays all have the same length.  So you can calculate that up front before entering the loops.

Try something like this:

```pascal
type
  TStrArr = array of string;
  PStrArr = ^TStrArr;
  TData = array of TStrArr;

procedure CopyResult(aResultCount: Integer; var aResult: TData; aSource: Variant);
var
  i, j,
  OuterLBound, OuterHBound, OuterCount,
  InnerLBound, InnerHBound, InnerCount: Integer;
  pOuterVarArr, pInnerVarArr: PVariant;
  pOuterDynArr: PStrArr;
  pInnerDynArr: PString;
  bVariantConversion: boolean;
begin    
  aResult := nil;

  Assert(VarIsType(aSource, varArray or varVariant));
  Assert(VarArrayDimCount(aSource) = 1);

  OuterLBound := VarArrayLowBound(aSource, 1);
  OuterHBound := VarArrayHighBound(aSource, 1);
  OuterCount := {aResultCount} OuterHBound - OuterLBound + 1;

  if OuterCount < 1 then Exit;

  Assert(VarIsType(aSource[0], varArray or varVariant));
  Assert(VarArrayDimCount(aSource[0]) = 1);

  InnerLBound := VarArrayLowBound(aSource[0], 1);
  InnerHBound := VarArrayHighBound(aSource[0], 1);
  InnerCount := InnerHBound - InnerLBound + 1;

  SetLength(aResult, {aResultCount} OuterCount, InnerCount);

  bVariantConversion := NullStrictConvert; // settings to manage how string conversion for Variant is handled.
  NullStrictConvert := False;
  try
    pOuterDynArr := PStrArr(aResult);
    pOuterVarArr := PVariant(VarArrayLock(aSource));
    try
      for i := OuterLBound to OuterHBound do
      begin
        pInnerDynArr := PString(pOuterDynArr^);
        pInnerVarArr := PVariant(VarArrayLock(pOuterVarArr^));
        try
          //System.Variants.DynArrayFromVariant(pOuterDynArr^, pInnerVarArr^, TypeInfo(String));

          for j := InnerLBound to InnerHBound do
          begin
            pInnerDynArr^ := pInnerVarArr^; //implicit conversion to string ... 
            Inc(pInnerDynArr);
            Inc(pInnerVarArr);
          end;
        finally
          VarArrayUnlock(pOuterVarArr^);
        end;
        Inc(pOuterDynArr);
        Inc(pOuterVarArr);
      end;
    finally
      VarArrayUnlock(aSource);
    end;
  finally
    NullStrictConvert := bVariantConversion;
  end;
end;
```

On the other hand, if there is ever a chance that the inner arrays have different lengths, then you can try this adjustment instead:

```pascal
type
  TStrArr = array of string;
  PStrArr = ^TStrArr;
  TData = array of TStrArr;

procedure CopyResult(aResultCount: Integer; var aResult: TData; aSource: Variant);
var
  i, j,
  OuterLBound, OuterHBound, OuterCount,
  InnerLBound, InnerHBound, InnerCount: Integer;
  pOuterVarArr, pInnerVarArr: PVariant;
  pOuterDynArr: PStrArr;
  pInnerDynArry: PString;
  bVariantConversion: boolean;
begin    
  aResult := nil;

  Assert(VarIsType(aSource, varArray or varVariant);
  Assert(VarArrayDimCount(aSource) = 1);

  OuterLBound := VarArrayLowBound(aSource, 1);
  OuterHBound := VarArrayHighBound(aSource, 1);
  OuterCount := {aResultCount} OuterHBound - OuterLBound + 1;

  if OuterCount < 1 then Exit;

  SetLength(aResult, {aResultCount} OuterCount);

  bVariantConversion := NullStrictConvert; // settings to manage how string conversion for Variant is handled.
  NullStrictConvert := False;
  try
    pOuterDynArr := PStrArr(aResult);
    pOuterVarArr := PVariant(VarArrayLock(aSource));
    try
      for i := OuterLBound to OuterHBound do
      begin
        pInnerVarArr := PVariant(VarArrayLock(pOuterVarArr^));
        try
          //System.Variants.DynArrayFromVariant(pOuterDynArr^, pInnerVarArr^, TypeInfo(String));

          Assert(VarIsType(pInnerVarArr^, varArray or varVariant);
          Assert(VarArrayDimCount(pInnerVarArr^) = 1);

          InnerLBound := VarArrayLowBound(pInnerVarArr^, 1);
          InnerHBound := VarArrayHighBound(pInnerVarArr^, 1);
          InnerCount := InnerHBound - InnerLBound + 1;

          SetLength(pOuterDynArr^, InnerCount);
          pInnerDynArr := PString(pOuterDynArr^);

          for j := InnerLBound to InnerHBound do
          begin
            pInnerDynArr^ := pInnerVarArr^; //implicit conversion to string ... 
            Inc(pInnerDynArr);
            Inc(pInnerVarArr);
          end;
        finally
          VarArrayUnlock(pOuterVarArr^);
        end;
        Inc(pOuterDynArr);
        Inc(pOuterVarArr);
      end;
    finally
      VarArrayUnlock(aSource);
    end;
  finally
    NullStrictConvert := bVariantConversion;
  end;
end;
```

Edit: I Only tested the Source version for all Entrys the same length but it works my own partial [] free Version used ~5 Million cycles with Tstopwatch ElapsedTicks and this one only took around ~2 Millon (more like 1.6) Thanks